# Template class methods definition with enable_if as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9652531/368599) earlier where [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9652733/368599) was presented. The solution is great as far as the question is concerned, but now I am confused on how I would define the methods *outside* of the class i.e. I would like to define the methods in an `.inl` file. What would be the syntax in this case?

Just to be clear, for a template class, the method definition will be:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
  Foo();
};

// C-tor definition
template <typename T>
Foo<T>::Foo()
{
}
```

How would I define methods for the template class with `enable_if` as one of the parameters?

```
template <typename Policy, enable_if< is_base<BasePolicy, Policy>::value >::type >
struct Foo
{
  Foo();
};

// C-tor definition -- ???
```

Comment: The same as you would if you defined it inline? What's the problem?

Comment: @KerrekSB: I am not sure about the syntax... my current attempts at extracting the constructor to the `inl` file resulted in an error: `{ctor}: is not a member of Foo<T, DerivedPolicy1>`. Defining it within the struct itself compiles fine.

Comment: I think the problem is that the "solution" posted earlier isn't really a solution: you need to extract the type from `enable_if<...>` or the `bool` from `enable_if_c<...>` and use it as [the default for] a template parameter. Once this is done it is clear how out of line definition would look like.

Comment: @DietmarKuhl: Yes, I did extract the type and the type is used as the template argument instead of the default parameter (I did not put it in the question, I will fix that right now). Again, would appreciate if I could get the syntax for the definition of a template method with the template parameters above.

Comment: I think my point is that this still doesn't make sense: the primary definition of `Foo` seems to be a template with one type argument. The use of `enable_if<...>::type` adds another type argument - this won't work.

Comment: @DietmarKuhl: I get your point, but please understand that my code works and that I know how to use `enable_if` for template class specializations as long as the definitions are in line. I just need to get the definitions OUT of the class itself, which is the problem here. All I am asking for is the syntax, it doesn't matter whether the code in the question above works or not.

Comment: The snippet you posted above most certainly **does not** work because `Foo` is defined to be a template with either one template argument or with two. If you slip a few `typename` keywords and an `=` into the primary template definition (as in my answer) it does work. Whether this is what you want I'm not sure, though: it prevents `Foo` from being instantiated with an error. You might want to have a look at `std::conditional` to get hold of two type which can then be used in their respective definitions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8767/discussion-between-samaursa-and-dietmar-kuhl)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the looks of it, you want to do something along the lines of this:

```
template <typename Policy,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<BasePolicy, Policy>::value>::type >
struct Foo;

template <typename Policy>
struct Foo<Policy> {
    Foo();
};

template <typename Policy>
Foo<Policy>::Foo() {
}
```

This sneakily takes advantage of the default argument in a few places: don't get confused, there is an implicit `void` sitting in several locations.

Comment: `is_base_of` is C++11... is the reasoning with the implicit `void` also a C++11 property? I am getting the same error as I put in other comments (`error C2039: {ctor}: is not a member of ...`)

Comment: Ohh, very nice trick with the forward declaration containing the template condition. Thanks!

Comment: Um... What exactly is the purpose of splitting this template into a "main template" and a specialization? Why didn't you just implement everything as the main template? When wrong `Policy` is used, the default argument will trigger an error. When right `Policy` is used, the compilation will proceed. What am I missing here? Why did you feel the need to separate the implementation into a specialization of the main template? The [more widespread] technique used in Luc Danton's answer does rely on a specialization. But what you are doing here is a bit different.

Comment: @AnT: where do you see a _specialization_? There is a _declaration_ of a `struct` which isn’t a definition followed by its _definition_. Likewise, there is a _declaration_ of a [member] function followed by a _definition_ thereof. Each of these _could_ be folded into just one declaration. It seemed the question was how to separate the declaration and the definition without repeating the condition when things should exist (I don’t recall the details from 7 years ago).

Comment: @DietmarKühl No, that is incorrect. The first declaration is indeed a non-defining declaration, as you correctly stated. But the second declaration is obviously **not** a definition for the first. The second declaration is a definition of a **partial specialization** of the first. Hence my question.

Comment: @AnT: oh - indeed! There is an excess `<Policy>`: that should probably be removed. I don’t think I had any particular reason to put it there and either approach works. Not specializing is probably more in the spirit of the original question and I’ll edit the answer. Thanks for pointing it out and insisting!

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl: First version was correct! this one doesn't compile. please revert it.

Answer (score 9):

Here's how SFINAE can actually work with partial specialization:

```
template<typename T, typename Sfinae = void>
struct Foo {
    /* catch-all primary template */
    /* or e.g. leave undefined if you don't need it */
};

template<typename T>
struct Foo<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<BasePolicy, T>::value>::type> {
    /* matches types derived from BasePolicy */
    Foo();
};
```

The definition for that constructor can then be awkwardly introduced with:

```
template<typename T>
Foo<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<BasePolicy, T>::value>::type>::Foo()
{
    /* Phew, we're there */
}
```

If your compiler supports template aliases (it's a C++11 feature) that then you can cut a lot of the verbosity:

```
template<typename T>
using EnableIfPolicy = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<BasePolicy, T>::value>::type;

// Somewhat nicer:

template<typename T>
struct Foo<T, EnableIfPolicy<T>> {
    Foo();
};

template<typename T>
Foo<T, EnableIfPolicy<T>>::Foo() {}
```

Note: your original answer referred to utilies from Boost, like `boost::enable_if_c` and `boost::is_base_of`. If you're using that instead of `std::enable_if` and `std::is_base_of` (which are from C++11), then usage looks like

```
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_case_of<BasePolicy, T> >::type
```

which has the advantage of getting rid of one `::value`.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax. It is, however, not working for me :( ... I get: `error C2039: {ctor}: is not a member of ...`

Comment: @Samaursa Terribly sorry, I did check that my compiler accepts the snippet, but I don't really know if it's in fact possible to refer to members of such a partial specialization. So I don't know if the error of your compiler is justified or not.

Comment: Your snippet is `C++11` although the only thing different is the usage of `std::enable_if` vs. `boost::enable_if`. Not sure why my compiler (VC++ 2008) is rejecting the definition.

Comment: SFINAE with partial specialization has been available in C++03 sort of kind of (IIRC it was formally a grey area that was fixed for C++11), the only C++11-relevant parts are `std::enable_if`/`std::is_base_of` to which I showed the Boost alternatives. The issue rests solely on whether defining the member out of line is possible at all, and if your compiler supports that.

Comment: I started a discussion with Kuhl and he gave me a code snippet which worked on my compiler (similar to what you put here) so the problem has been narrowed down to my code. Thanks for the help and explanations (+1). I always wished SO allowed multiple correct answers!