# Enable_if as template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, enable-if

Please tell me why [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659955/template-class-methods-definition-with-enable-if-as-template-parameter/9660236#9660236) works.

1. What happened to the enable_if such we can omit it after that? (further usage of Foo struct doesn't need that enable_if in template parameters)
2. Should not that code be something like this:

Origin version:

```
template <typename Policy,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<BasePolicy, Policy>::value>::type >
struct Foo;

template <typename Policy>
struct Foo {
    Foo();
};

template <typename Policy>
Foo<Policy>::Foo() {
}
```

Edited version:

```
template <typename Policy,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<BasePolicy, Policy>::value>::type >
struct Foo;

template <typename Policy>
struct Foo<Policy> {  // <Policy> added!
    Foo();
};

template <typename Policy>
Foo<Policy>::Foo() {
}
```

Comment: *"What happen to the enable_if such we can omit it after that?"* - After what? ... Please can you make your question a bit clearer?

Comment: it would be good if you included also the original code to make the differences easier accesible

Comment: I made it clear and added original code

Comment: Who said the original *has* to work? It's a mistake made by the author.

Comment: It has the `<Policy>` first but the author removed it in the new edition. Check edit history and comments.

Comment: I think the original was simply wrong.

Comment: Can anybody explains why even the edited version works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened:

1. The author posted working code (`<Policy>` was present);
2. There was some discussion in the comments that led the author to edit the code, and he made a mistake (`<Policy>` was removed);
3. I rectified the mistake putting back the missing `<Policy>`.

---

> Can anybody explains why even the edited version works?

When you attempt to instantiate `Foo<T>`, the declaration with the default template parameters is taken into account by the compiler. The default parameter is evaluated and if `std::is_base_of<BasePolicy, Policy>::value` is `false` then `enable_if` produces a SFINAE-friendly error.

If `std::is_base_of<BasePolicy, Policy>::value` is `true`, the partial specialization is chosen.

```
template <typename Policy>
struct Foo<Policy> {
    Foo() { } 
};

// is equivalent to

template <typename Policy>
struct Foo<Policy, void> {
    Foo() { } 
};
```

The above specializations are equivalent because `typename std::enable_if<true>::type` is `void` by default.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. can you explain why correct version works? I mean which feature of C++ make this magic happen?

Comment: @MOHRE: added an explanation

Comment: You are a `Policy`.

Comment: @SombreroChicken: You are merely a `BasePolicy`.